# What is a good way to add group functionality with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, grouping, models

I am trying to add group functionality for my users. I have never used the Groupify gem and I just found out about it . Is it a reliable gem to introduce group functionality to my website ? Is it flexible ?
What would you recommend, programming the group thing completely from scratch or using groupify ? Are there other gems you know of that do the same thing ?

I would like to start with Groups such as : Admin, Moderator, Artist. The members of these groups are all users but have certain privileges the basic user does not have.
And I would also like to give members of these basic groups the ability to create new groups for mostly discussion purposes and information sharing.

Thanks !!

Comment: By groups do you mean "Administrators", "Staff", "Users" etc?

Comment: Yes. And ordinary users will also be grouped depending on areas of interests

Comment: Great. I recommend updating your question to include the Groups you would like and details on those groups. Sounds like you have "roles" and "groups". Roles being Admin etc, Groups being based on interests. It would be nice to see what ideas you already have come up as a possible solution as well, if any.

Comment: I had a look at Groupify, it looks great to me. Any reasons why you don't want to use it? Give it a go? If you don't go down the Groupify path, the relationship you talk about is very simple ActiveRecord Models and Relationships.

Comment: Tried groupify and I am running into the same problem as indicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112512/rails-groupify-gem

Comment: You have to call `User.create` or `user.save` at some point to get your models persisted into the database.